# Too few records from DBpedia

Tags: linked-data, dbpedia

I run the following query to get Athletes data from DBpedia:

```
  SELECT * WHERE {

  ?player a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete> .
  ?player foaf:name ?firstname .
  ?player foaf:surname ?lastname .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country> ?birthplace .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate> ?birthDate .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person/height> ?height .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person/weight> ?weight .
}
```

but it only returns about 300 records! What's the problem with my query?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 SELECT (count(?player) as ?count) WHERE {

  ?player a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete> .
  ?player foaf:name ?firstname .
  ?player foaf:surname ?lastname .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country> ?birthplace .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate> ?birthDate .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person/height> ?height .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person/weight> ?weight .
 }
```

I guess there are only 283 matching results for this query.

Also check

```
SELECT (count(?player) as ?count) 
WHERE {
       ?player a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete> .
      }

SELECT ?player 
WHERE {
       ?player a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete> .
      }
```